# how to get site collection url from SharePoint Hosted App

Tags: site-collection, url, sharepoint-hosted-app

I am trying to get site collection URL using

> _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl

but it is giving output as `https://domain.-a08083bbaacc988.sharePoint.com/sites/sitecollectionname`

but I want it as `https://domain.sharePoint.com/sites/sitecollectionname` that is without instance id

How to get site collection url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your SharePoint Hosted app what you can get context of host web and fetch the url of site collection
You can use `RequestExecutor` for cross domain request as

```
 $.getScript(hostUrl + "/_layouts/15/" + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", GetSiteUrl);
```

and then fetch URL of sitecollection using bellow function

```
function GetSiteUrl() {
    var hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
    var currentcontext = new SP.ClientContext()
    var hostcontext = new SP.AppContextSite(currentcontext, hostUrl);
    var site = hostcontext.get_site();
    currentcontext.load(site);
    currentcontext.executeQueryAsync(function (s, a) {
        sitecollectionurl = site.get_url()

    });
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 4):

In your App url there are various Query String Parameters as shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163816.aspx). That already containts the site collection url.

The Query String paramter "SPHostUrl" will give you the site collection URl.

In order to get that URL you can use following code

```
function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
var params =document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
var strParams = "";
for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
return singleParam[1];
}
}
```

Just use this code as

```
hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl")
```

Now this `hostweburl` will contain your site collection URL. For code reference you can see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nickpinheiro/2015/01/30/build-a-sharepoint-hosted-app-to-access-list-data-in-your-host-web-using-the-rest-api-in-10-easy-steps/)

Comment: but how can we predict the site collection url

Comment: You don't need to predict. It will give the url of the site collection on which the app is installed

Comment: I don't want host web url, I want to fetch site collection url (root of subsites )

Comment: Yes, the parameter I have specified it will give you what you want. please try once and then let me know. its working code I am daily used to SharePoint hosted app.

Comment: You can just copy your full url and paste it in notepad and see the parameter "SPHostUrl" will contain your site collection url

Comment: suppose my app is deployed in _https://domain.sharePoint.com/sites/sitecollectionname/subsite1/subsite2_  then its host web is _https://domain.sharePoint.com/sites/sitecollectionname/subsite1/subsite2_  and site collection url must be _https://domain.sharePoint.com/sites/sitecollectionname/_

Comment: then you need to do a string manipulation part using jquery to extract particular portion.

Comment: I have refer but it only gives host web url