# Redirect From one app page to another SharePoint Hosted App

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app, redirect

Currenlt I am creating SharePoint hosted App. In which I have 2 pages Default .aspx and dashboard.aspx in Pages folder.
Now I want to redirect page from Default to dashboard.aspx.
One way I know is
      `window.location = window.location.href.replace('Default.aspx', 'Dashboard.aspx');`
But sometimes Default.aspx might have '#' key word at last,hence doesnt work many times and also we dont know if some other key work might come in default.aspx's URL. Hence want to any URL string manipulation. 
Please provide me some  alternate solution in javascipt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `windows.location.hash` contains the anchor part of a URL. So

```
windows.location.assign(windows.location.href.replace(windows.location.hash,""));
```

[Location Object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Use Relative Url to redirect to your custom pages Default Or Dashboard. This way you don't need to worry about URL hash #.

Simply use

```
window.location.href = "/sites/your-site/Pages/Dashboard.aspx"
```

This works 100% as it automatically  calculates the domain and other params to form a web Url

Comment: there also we need SPHostUrl and someother parameter. In URL you mention doesnt contain complete required URL.

Comment: I am only concerned to site Relative url. I know, this is a SP hosted app but one can easily get site url from both HOSTweb and APPweb Url. After this, it is a simple string manipulation problem.

Comment: Refer This Thread : https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/189927/how-to-get-site-collection-url-from-sharepoint-hosted-app?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa  .. I hope this answers your query