# How to get Host Web URL in App Domain?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

In my SharePoint hosted app, I am getting an URL like `https://<Domain>-ffc9b07d6c583f.sharepoint.com/sites/Trial/EMS/Pages/Default.aspx` but I need to achieve like this`https://<Domain>.sharepoint.com/sites/Trial/EMS/Pages/Default.aspx`.

I have gone through [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/189927/how-to-get-site-collection-url-from-sharepoint-hosted-app), but it works only in the case if I have *SPHostUrl* in the Query strings. Kindly suggest

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatelly there is no easy way how to get the host web url. You can simply remove the part between dash and first dot. The text between them is dynamic and changes with each new version of application. But it is always in the same format.

```
var url = "https://<Domain>-ffc9b07d6c583f.sharepoint.com/sites/Trial/EMS/Pages/Default.aspx";
url.replace(url.substring(url.indexOf("-"), url.indexOf(".")), "");
```